# SQL Server support end - different terms

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing

I was going through the end support date of SQL Server 2008. I found following dates for different kind of support and would like to understand the difference between them as product consumer/developer.

7-8-2014 - **Mainstream support**

7-9-2019 - **Extended support**

4-13-2010 - **SP support end**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **licensing** and definitely not about ***programming*** which this site is all about. Please respect the rules of the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Mainstream support—Microsoft** will offer mainstream support for a minimum of 5 years from the date of a product's general availability,
>   or for 2 years after the successor product is released, whichever is
>   longer. For example, if you buy a new version of Windows and five
>   years later another version is released, you will still have two years
>   of support left for the previous version.
>
> **Extended support—Microsoft** will offer extended support for either a minimum of 5 years from the date of a product's general
>   availability, or for 2 years after the second successor product (two
>   versions later) is released, whichever is longer.
>
> A **service pack (SP)** is a Windows update, often combining
>   previously released updates, that helps make Windows more reliable.
>   Service packs, which are provided free of charge on this page, can
>   include security and performance improvements and support for new
>   types of hardware. Make sure you install the latest service pack to
>   help keep Windows up to date. Service packs take about 30 minutes to
>   install, and you'll need to restart your computer about halfway
>   through the installation.

*Sources*

[`What is the difference between mainstream support and extended support?`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/lifecycle)

[`Service Pack and Update Center`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/service-packs-download#sptabs=win7)